# MYSQL MIN in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, min

OK, so I'm working on a home theater system, and to display the list of TV series I have been selecting the first episode of the first season and displaying the associated information for just that episode, then you can drill down to others.

That way I can keep all the movies and all the TV shows in a single table which makes the playback functions much easier.

The problem is, some of the series I don't have the first episode in the database, and I want them to appear anyway, so I want to select the minimum season/series instead of the first.

I can't put `MIN` in the select clause as then it only selects one series, and I can't put `LEAST` in the `WHERE` clause because it says it's only one element because of the way they're grouped, and I can't use `LIMIT` because again then it will only select one series.

Is there a way to do this without multiple complicated subqueries?

Here's the query I'm using at the moment, the `CASE` clause is to remove A/An/The from the series title for proper alphabetical order:

```
SELECT *, CASE when substring(series,1,4) = 'The ' then substring(series, 5)
               when substring(series,1,3) = 'An ' then substring(series, 4)
               when substring(series,1,2) = 'A ' then substring(series, 3)
               else series END AS sorttitle 
FROM Theater.Videos WHERE type='TV' and season=1 and episode=1 ORDER BY sorttitle ASC
```

And here's essentially what I want:

```
SELECT *, CASE when substring(series,1,4) = 'The ' then substring(series, 5)
               when substring(series,1,3) = 'An ' then substring(series, 4)
               when substring(series,1,2) = 'A ' then substring(series, 3)
               else series END AS sorttitle 
FROM Theater.Videos WHERE type='TV' and season=MIN(season) and episode=MIN(episode) ORDER BY sorttitle ASC
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data along with expected output?

Comment: Table layout is below in response to the second answer; The 600 characters it's giving me here isn't really enough to put in sample data but essentially you'd have a set of results that *usually* have identical data in every one of those columns except season and episode. Series/season/episode combined are unique, though I haven't set a constraint on that right now. Those fields are also only expected to be null where type != 'tv', though that is also not enforced (not sure that it can be.) Both those constraints are enforced by the application, so the data meets them, just not in table layout

Comment: 1. Do you want to see the first episode of each season for a series or the first episode of the first season of the series.

Comment: 2. Is there any reason to do this in one query? Would this be wrapped around by some other code (php/python/etc) so that you can use multiple queries which in my opinion would be better to minimize complexity (and maybe even improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these queries (after suitable modification)...

To get list of all series along with first episode of the first (min) season use this...

```
select distinct v1.*
from videos v1,
    (select series, min(season) as min_season from videos group by series) as v2,
    (select series, season, min(episode) as min_episode from videos group by series, season) as v3
where v1.series = v2.series
and v1.season = v2.min_season
and v2.series = v3.series
and v2.min_season = v3.season
and v1.episode = v3.min_episode
```

To get list of all series along with first episode of each season use this...

```
select distinct v1.*
from videos v1,
    (select series, season, min(episode) as min_episode from videos group by series, season) as v3
where v1.series = v3.series
and v1.season = v3.season
and v1.episode = v3.min_episode
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the table to itself using a subquery with `MIN()` -- this should be close:

```
SELECT V.*, CASE when substring(V.series,1,4) = 'The ' then substring(V.series, 5)
               when substring(V.series,1,3) = 'An ' then substring(V.series, 4)
               when substring(V.series,1,2) = 'A ' then substring(V.series, 3)
               else V.series END AS sorttitle 
FROM Theater.Videos V
    JOIN (
        SELECT series, Min(season) MinSeason, MIN(Episode) MinEpisode
        FROM Theater.Videos
        GROUP BY series
    ) t ON t.series = V.series 
        AND t.season = V.MinSeason 
        AND t.episode = V.MinEpisode
WHERE V.type='TV' 
ORDER BY V.sorttitle ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

its hard to say something without seen tha DB structure. If you can please put the sample overview of your db table.
or assign the where condition part in to a variable and first check that the series which do not have the first episode and get the results using while loop. after end of the while execute the next where condition according to your logic.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `series` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `season` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `episode` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `synopsis` text,
  `synopsis_full` text NOT NULL,
  `imdb_url` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `imdb_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `file` (`file`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;